# Passing Generic List to Method

Tags: c#-4.0

I'm trying to create a method that accepts lists of any type so I don't have to create a method to handle every type of list object. It says my l object variable is invalid.

My code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           List <Person> l;
            testList(l);
        }

        public void testList(List<object> x)
        {

        }
```

Comment: Did you make it work? I hope I answered your question! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           List <Person> list1;
           testList<Person>(list1);

           List <OtherClassObj> list2;
           testList<OtherClassObj>(list2)
        }

        //Here T is type of object
        public void testList<T>(List<T> x)
        {
            if (typeof(T) == typeof(Person))
                //Prosess Person's List
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your method generic also (by  adding a generic parameter to the method). This should work, but make sure you assign your List (e.g. `List<Person l = new List<Person>();`).

```
public void testList<T>(List<T> X)
    {
       // Whatever you want to do with your list.
    }
```

Also, just a reminder, looks like you're calling it from a static method, make sure to add static on the method as well.

Hope it helps!